# TexStudio does not open containing folder

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, nautilus-actions

I recently did a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install and then installed TexStudio 3.1.2. Nothing happens when I right-click a document and select "Open containing folder". I'm not sure if this is an Ubuntu configuration issue or a TexStudio issue. It used to work just fine in 18.04 before I upgraded, but I don't recall which version of TexStudio I had then. Similar options work just fine in Matlab. I'd appreciate some help troubleshooting and solving this problem. TIA

EDIT
The output of `apt-cache policy texstudio`

```
texstudio:
  Installed: 3.1.2-0~202105130932~ubuntu20.04.1
  Candidate: 3.1.2-0~202105130932~ubuntu20.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.1.2-0~202105130932~ubuntu20.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sunderme/texstudio/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.12.22+debian-1build1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: How did you installed TeXStudio? Please show the output of `apt-cache policy texstudio`, `snap list | grep -i TexStudio` and `flatpak list | grep -i TexStudio` .

Comment: @N0rbert I used the PPA. I've edited the post to include the output of `apt-cache policy texstudio`

Comment: Tried updated TexStudio 3.1.2 on 20.04.3 LTS on both GNOME and MATE, can't reproduce the issue. Some additional info needed to reproduce, it seems.